# Category theory - Prove that $\operatorname{Hom}$ preserves representations for quasi-inverse functors

Tags: category-theory, representable-functor

> Let $F: \mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ and $G: \mathcal D \to \mathcal C$ be quasi-inverse functors, and let $H : \mathcal C \to Set$ be a representable (contravariant) functor with representative $X \in \mathcal C$. Prove that $H \circ G$ is representable by $F(X)$.

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}$As ismorphisms are transitive, it suffices to consider the case when $H = \Hom( -, X)$. To this end, we wish to find $\phi : \Hom(-,X) \circ G \to \Hom(-,F(X))$ an ismorphism, from which we quickly deduce that for any $f: B \to A$ and $g: GA \to X$ it must be that $\phi_A(g) \circ f = \phi_B(g \circ Gf)$. I am not sure how to dind such a $\phi$ though. It seems like I have to somehow use the fact that $F$ and $G$ are quasi-inverses...

Comment: Start with the map, then prove it's an isomorphism, then that it's natural. Given $Y$ and $f\in (Hom(-,X)\circ G)(Y)=Hom(G(Y),X))$, how do you get a corresponding element of $Hom(-,F(X))(Y)=Hom(Y,F(X))$?

Comment: Thanks @KevinCarlson, could you elaborate as an answer? I tried $Y \to G(Y) \to GFG(Y) \to G(Y) \to X \to F(X)$ but I am not sure whether flapping down the FG part (from $GFG(Y)$ to $G(Y)$) is justified, since it's inside.

Comment: Those arrows can't possible all mean the same thing. For instance, $Y$ and $G(Y)$ aren't in the same category, while the middle four objects are...It seems like you might be a bit confused about the basic definitions around functors. I'm unlikely to write out a full answer, because I'm doubtful whether either you or the community would benefit much from that. You've been asking a whole lot of questions in a row that you'll be able to solve handily on your own with a bit more conceptual clarification. But I'm happy to try to clarify further and maybe someone else will write an answer.

Comment: @KevinCarlson, thank you for your comment. Unfortunately I am very new to category theory (I am only 2 weeks from starting it) and even this basic questuon confuses me, I have literally been trying this question for hours - I didn't post this problem because I was being lazy. If you could please clarify your answer that would be great.

Comment: I do get the basic idea here, that F and G are "almost" inverses, so that we can essentially "backtrack" to get the desired "equality" (i.e. isomorphism) we want. However, I am struggling to get the details right...

Comment: Also, looking at your post I realize that you are into category theory. Is there any tip for a student who is struggling to get the details right? Because there are so much "structure inside structure" stuff in category theory, I often find myself very very confused

Comment: OK, I helped you out with the key definitions. Let me know how it's looking now. Apologies for seeming to imply you were being lazy, which was not by any means my intent.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** The map $\phi$ is defined, if $f:G(Y)\to X$, by $\phi(f)=F(f)\circ \varepsilon^{-1}_Y$. Here, $\varepsilon^{-1}_Y:Y\to FG(Y)$ is the inverse of the "counit of the adjunction", that is, one of the natural isomorphisms that proves that $F$ and $G$ are quasi-inverses. In the other direction, $\phi^{-1}$ sends $g:Y\to F(X)$ to  $\eta_X^{-1}\circ G(g)$, where $G(g):G(Y)\to GF(X)$ and $\eta_X:X\to GF(X)$ is the other natural isomorphism coming with the equivalence. Now you just have to check that $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ are mutually inverse and (that one, thus the other is) natural.

Answer (score 1):

> $\newcommand\cat\mathscr\DeclareMathOperator\id{id}$Let $F:\cat C\rightleftarrows\cat D:G$ be quasi-inverse functors.
>   Then $F,G$ are fully faithful and there exists natural isomorphisms $\varepsilon:F\circ G\to\id_{\cat C}$ and $\eta:\id_{\cat D}\to G\circ F$ such that
>   \begin{align}
> &\eta_GG(\varepsilon)=1_G&
> &F(\eta)\varepsilon_F=1_F
> \end{align}

*Proof.*
Let $\bar\eta:\id_{\cat D}\to G\circ F$ be a natural isomorphism.

The functor $F$ is faithful, for if $u,v:A\rightrightarrows B$ and $F(u)=F(v)$ then
\begin{align}
u\bar\eta_B
&=\bar\eta_A(G\circ F)(u)\\
&=\bar\eta_A(G\circ F)(v)\\
&=v\bar\eta_B
\end{align}
which implies $u=v$. Similarly, $G$ is faithful.

The functor $F$ is full, for if $y:F(A)\to F(B)$ and $x=\bar\eta_AG(y)\bar\eta_B^{-1}$, then
\begin{align}
\bar\eta_A(G\circ F)(x)
&=x\bar\eta_B\\
&=\bar\eta_AG(y)
\end{align}
which implies $y=F(x)$ (since $G$ is faithful).

Let $\varepsilon:F\circ G\to\id_{\cat C}$ be a natural isomorphism.
Since $F$ is full and faithful, for each object $A$ in $\cat C$ there exists one and only one isomorphism $\eta_A:A\to (G\circ F)(A)$ such that $F(\eta_A)=\varepsilon_{F(A)}^{-1}$.
Then $\eta:\id_{\cat C}\to G\circ F$ is a natural isomorphism (again using faithfulness of $F $) and $F(\eta)\varepsilon_F=1_F$.

By naturalness of $\varepsilon$, we have $\varepsilon_{F\circ G}\varepsilon=(F\circ G)(\varepsilon)\varepsilon$ from which we get $\varepsilon_{F\circ G}=(F\circ G)(\varepsilon)$.
Consequently,
\begin{align}
F(\eta_GG(\varepsilon))
&=F(\eta_G)(F\circ G)(\varepsilon)\\
&=F(\eta_G)\varepsilon_{F\circ G}\\
&=1_{F\circ G}\\
&=F(1_G)
\end{align}
from which $\eta_GG(\varepsilon)=1_G$. $\square$

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom} $For all objects $A$ of $\cat C$ we define
\begin{align}
&\varphi_A:\Hom_{\cat C}(G(A),X)\to\Hom_{\cat D}(A,F(X))&
&f\mapsto\varepsilon_A^{-1}F(f)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
&\psi_A:\Hom_{\cat D}(A,F(X))\to\Hom_{\cat C}(G(A),X)&
&g\mapsto G(g)\eta_X^{-1}
\end{align}

We have to show that $\varphi_A$ is natural in $A$ and $\varphi_A\circ\psi_A$ and $\psi_A\circ\varphi_A$ are identity functions.

For all $f:G(A)\to X$ we have
\begin{align}
(\psi_A\circ\varphi_A)(f)
&=G(\varepsilon_A^{-1}F(f))\eta_X^{-1}\\
&=G(\varepsilon_A)^{-1}(G\circ F)(f)\eta_X^{-1}\\
&=\eta_{G(A)}(G\circ F)(f)\eta_X^{-1}\\
&=f\eta_X\eta_X^{-1}\\
&=f
\end{align}

For all $g:A\to F(X)$ we have
\begin{align}
(\varphi_A\circ\psi_A)(g)
&=\varepsilon_A^{-1}F(G(g)\eta_X^{-1})\\
&=\varepsilon_A^{-1}(F\circ G)(g)F(\eta_X)^{-1}\\
&=\varepsilon_A^{-1}(F\circ G)(g)\varepsilon_{F(X)}\\
&=\varepsilon_A^{-1}\varepsilon_Ag\\
&=g
\end{align}

Let $u:B\to A$ be a morphism in $\cat C$.
Then naturalness of $\varphi_A$ means 
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Hom_{\cat C}(G(A),X) @>\varphi_A>> \Hom_{\cat D}(A,F(X))\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\Hom_{\cat C}(G(B),X) @>>\varphi_B> \Hom_{\cat D}(B,F(X))
\end{CD}$$
For all $f:G(A)\to X$ we have
\begin{align}
\varphi_B(G(u)f)
&=\varepsilon_B^{-1}F(G(u)f)\\
&=\varepsilon_B^{-1}(F\circ G)(u)F(f)\\
&=u\varepsilon_A^{-1}F(f)\\
&=u\varphi_A(f)
\end{align}