# Proving equivalent categories have binary products if one of them does

Tags: category-theory, natural-transformations

Suppose $\mathscr{C},\mathscr{D}$ are equivalent categories.

Then there exist functors $S∶ \mathscr{C}\rightarrow \mathscr{D}$ and $T∶\mathscr{D}→\mathscr{C}$ with the compositions defined $T\circ S∶ \mathscr{C}→\mathscr{C}$ and $S\circ T∶ \mathscr{D}\rightarrow\mathscr{D}$, and a pair of natural isomorphisms $\alpha∶T\circ S \rightarrow 1_\mathscr{C}$ and $\beta ∶S\circ T\rightarrow1_\mathscr{D}.$

We seek to prove that, if $\mathscr{C} $ has binary products, then $\mathscr{D} $ also does.

I'm not really sure how to even approach this one, there seems to be so much going on that it's almost dizzying. My gut instinct is that we could show $\mathscr{C}$ has limits (since aren't limits a way of formalizing the product?) and then ... somehow? ... show that $\mathscr{D}$ also has them, but I'm so unconfident in that even conceptually.

Any ideas or nudges?

Comment: No, you can't just magically make arbitrary limits out of binary products.

Comment: Okay then; what *am* I supposed to do in this?

Comment: So you want to construct a product of two objects $X$ and $Y$ of $\mathscr{D}$. You can construct binary products in $\mathscr{C}$, so you can construct a product of $T\left(X\right)$ and $T\left(Y\right)$. Furthermore, you can send this product back into $\mathscr{D}$ using $S$. Does this do the trick?

Comment: So $X,Y$ have image $T(X), T(Y)$ in $\mathscr{C}$. Since $\mathscr{C}$, by assumption, has binary products, then the object $T(X) \times T(Y)$ must also exist in $\mathscr{C}$. ... I'm a bit lost from there though. Obviously we can just send that product through $S$ back to $\mathscr{D}$, but that doesn't really invoke any assumptions about the equivalence of the categories, namely the natural transformations (among other probable issues). So it's obviously more nuanced than that.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer No, that's the right idea. The natural transformations go to show that $S$ sends the product to a product of $STX$ and $STY$, and thus of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Actually, I'm seeing that there is a short proof, too: The functors $S$ and $T$ are quasi-inverse equivalences, and thus are mutually adjoint (see Proposition 4.4.5 in [Emily Riehl, *Category theory in context*, 2018](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/context.pdf)). Thus, $S$ is right adjoint, and therefore preserves limits (by Theorem 4.5.2 in [op. cit.](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/context.pdf)). Now, pick two objects $X$ and $Y$ of $\mathscr{D}$. You want to prove that they have a product in $\mathscr{D}$. By assumption, ...

Comment: ... you know that the objects $T\left(X\right)$ and $T\left(Y\right)$ have a product in $\mathscr{C}$. This product is a limit, and thus is preserved by $S$. Hence, applying $S$ to it yields a product of the two objects $S\left(T\left(X\right)\right)$ and $S\left(T\left(Y\right)\right)$ in $\mathscr{D}$. So the objects $S\left(T\left(X\right)\right)$ and $S\left(T\left(Y\right)\right)$ have a product in $\mathscr{D}$. But these two objects are isomorphic to $X$ and $Y$, respectively (via the natural isomorphism $\beta$), and thus ...

Comment: ... the two objects $X$ and $Y$ must have a product as well (which is the same object as the product of $S\left(T\left(X\right)\right)$ and $S\left(T\left(Y\right)\right)$, while its arrows have been composed with the isomorphisms $S\left(T\left(X\right)\right) \to X$ and $S\left(T\left(Y\right)\right) \to Y$).

Comment: A hint to an alternative approach is that if $\mathscr Q_1\simeq \mathscr Q_2$ are equivalent, and $\mathscr R_1\simeq \mathscr R_2$ are equivalent, then $\mathscr R_1^{\mathscr Q_1}\simeq R_2^{\mathscr Q_2}$ are themselves equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X,Y$ be objects in $\mathscr D$ and
\begin{align}
&p:T(X)\times T(Y)\to T(X)&
&q:T(X)\times T(Y)\to T(Y)
\end{align}
be a product source in $\mathscr C$.
We claim that
\begin{align}
&S(p)\beta_X:S(T(X)\times T(Y))\to X&
&S(q)\beta_Y:S(T(X)\times T(Y))\to Y
\end{align}
is a product source in $\mathscr D$.
Let
\begin{align}
&u:Z\to X&
&v:Z\to Y
\end{align}
be a source in $\mathscr D$.
Then
\begin{align}
&T(u):T(Z)\to T(X)&
&T(v):T(Z)\to T(Y)
\end{align}
is a source in $\mathscr C$, hence there exists one and only one morphism $w:T(Z)\to T(X)\times T(Y)$ such that
\begin{align}
&T(u)=wp&
&T(v)=wq
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\beta^{-1}_ZS(w)S(p)\beta_X&=\beta^{-1}_Z(S\circ T)(u)\beta_X&
\beta^{-1}_ZS(w)S(q)\beta_Y&=\beta^{-1}_Z(S\circ T)(v)\beta_Y\\
&=\beta^{-1}_Z\beta_Zu&
&=\beta^{-1}_Z\beta_Zv\\
&=u&
&=v
\end{align}
which proves the existence part.
It remains to prove uniqueness.
For this, first recall that we can assume $\alpha^{-1}_TT(\beta)=1_T$ and $\beta^{-1}_SS(\alpha)=1_S$ (see, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2968930)).
Let $w':Z\to S(T(X)\times T(Y))$ such that
\begin{align}
&u=w'S(p)\beta_X&
&v=w'S(q)\beta_Y
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
T(u)&=\alpha_{T(Z)}^{-1}T(\beta_Z)T(w')\alpha_{T(X)\times T(Y)}p&
T(v)&=\alpha_{T(Z)}^{-1}T(\beta_Z)T(w')\alpha_{T(X)\times T(Y)}q\\
&=T(w')\alpha_{T(X)\times T(Y)}p&
&=T(w')\alpha_{T(X)\times T(Y)}q\\
\end{align}
from which $w=T(w')\alpha_{T(X)\times T(Y)}$.
Consequently,
\begin{align}
S(w)
&=\beta_Z\beta^{-1}_Z(S\circ T)(w')S(\alpha_{T(X)\times T(Y)})\\
&=\beta_Zw'\beta^{-1}_{S(T(X)\times T(Y))}S(\alpha_{T(X)\times T(Y)})\\
&=\beta_Zw'
\end{align}
thus concluding the proof.

Comment: Hmm. Your "source" means "cone in the particular case of a binary product", right? And you're writing composition the "other way round"?

Comment: Yes, you are right;

Comment: @FabioLucchini I think beginning students should be warned about a choice like reversing the traditional composition order!